# MongoDB Server Wouldent Run Properly On Windows

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've been trying to use mongodb shell but the server won't run,
I use to command prompt to navigate to cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin , and then , and I created the directory on c:\data\db ,
tried to start the mongod command and I got these errors:

> {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.262+02:00"},"s":"W", "c":"ASIO", "id":22601, "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.262+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"NETWORK", "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.264+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":8208,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-9DS43SR"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.264+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"CONTROL", "id":23398, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.264+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"CONTROL", "id":23403, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.3","gitVersion":"913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.264+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"CONTROL", "id":51765, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19041)"}}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.265+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"CONTROL", "id":21951, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"port":27017},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.268+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22270, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.268+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22315, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=11743M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.290+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22430, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1611131360:290563][8208:140735766484304], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 3"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.367+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22430, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1611131360:366530][8208:140735766484304], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 3"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.440+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22430, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1611131360:440366][8208:140735766484304], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 2/4224 to 3/256"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.577+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22430, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1611131360:576971][8208:140735766484304], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 3"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.659+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22430, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1611131360:658797][8208:140735766484304], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 3"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.728+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22430, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1611131360:727600][8208:140735766484304], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.728+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22430, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1611131360:728569][8208:140735766484304], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.750+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":481}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.750+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.752+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.753+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":22262, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.758+02:00"},"s":"W", "c":"CONTROL", "id":22140, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:20.760+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"STORAGE", "id":20536, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:21.474+02:00"},"s":"W", "c":"FTDC", "id":23718, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC","attr":{"error":{"code":179,"codeName":"WindowsPdhError","errmsg":"PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'The specified object was not found on the computer.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes'"}}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:21.474+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"FTDC", "id":20625, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:21.480+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"NETWORK", "id":23015, "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T10:29:21.481+02:00"},"s":"I", "c":"NETWORK", "id":23016, "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}

Comment: if your problem is not solved, leave a comment, if my answer is true accept it, thank you

Comment: It says `"msg":"Waiting for connections"` - so your database seems to be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

if you use mongodb 4.4 you don't need to create a new path to stored data beacuse default path is `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data` created by mongodb, check the status service, like photo, status should be `running` if status is stopped you should run `mognod.exe` and you see this messages, it's not a error

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-20T00:42:48.730-08:00"},"s":"I", and .....
```

and check status service again

[image: check status service mongoDB]